# pandas: how to read html and casting all fields to string

Tags: python, pandas

If I import [this HTML file](https://gist.github.com/aborruso/599153968878f452bd3c68f3de0f29c4/raw/1156d224a4290393409ceef285c238c09b6bd08e/input.html)

```
pd_df = pd.read_html('./output.html')
pd_df[0]
```

the last field becomes a float, but it's a string (in example from `05269` to `5269.0`). I know I can apply `pd_df = pd.read_html('./output.html',converters={'CAP': str})`, but my question is: is there a way to apply globally str casting to all fields, using read_html?

Because this is an example file, this is a simple example, but often I have a lot of fields and a global option would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(edited)

What you can do is read it twice. Once to get the column names, and then another time with converters to make sure all columns are read as `str`:

```
url = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/aborruso/599153968878f452bd3c68f3de0f29c4/raw/1156d224a4290393409ceef285c238c09b6bd08e/input.html"
df = pd.read_html(url)[0]


converters = {c:lambda x: str(x) for c in df.columns}

df = pd.read_html(url, converters=converters)[0]
print(df)
# results in: 

  Beneficiario       Comune    CAP Provincia Importo
0  RNDFNC60E16  RIPACANDIDA  85020   POTENZA   09269
1  RNDFNC60E16          NaN    NaN   POTENZA   05269

print(df.dtypes) 
# results in : 
Beneficiario    object
Comune          object
CAP             object
Provincia       object
Importo         object
dtype: object
```

Comment: Roy,  please look at the last field: the source value is 09269, and it becomes 9269. I want to import as string, because I do not want that pandas transform it. And I would like to apply string casting globally during import (as you do in read_csv using dtype=str)

Answer (score 1):

To address the issue you're facing with the `read_html` method in pandas, where numeric fields are incorrectly cast to floats instead of strings, you can use the `defaultdict` from the `collections` module. This approach allows you to automatically apply a string cast to all fields without needing to specify each column. Here's how you can do it:

```py
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

url = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/aborruso/599153968878f452bd3c68f3de0f29c4/raw/1156d224a4290393409ceef285c238c09b6bd08e/input.html"
df = pd.read_html(url, converters=defaultdict(str))[0]
```

This method will ensure that all columns in the DataFrame are treated as strings, regardless of their original format in the HTML file. It's a convenient way to handle datasets with numerous fields, where specifying each column's type individually would be impractical.

The resulting DataFrame will look like this:

```
  Beneficiario       Comune    CAP Provincia Importo
0  RNDFNC60E16  RIPACANDIDA  85020   POTENZA   09269
1  RNDFNC60E16          NaN    NaN   POTENZA   05269
```

Notice how the `CAP` field and others are preserved as strings, avoiding any unwanted type conversion.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

if we know number of columns:

```
df = pd.read_html("output.html",converters ={x:str for x in range(5)})[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same request, but couldn't find a straightforward solution online. Tested a few solutions, and I found quite simple one. List below for future who have the same request.

```
pd.read_html(url, parse_dates=False, thousands=";", decimal=";")
```

thousands & decimal can be anything, that don't exist in the web page. The result is every column in string format.

Answer (score 0):

Combine Roy2012's and Akhilesh_IN's answers

```
url = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/aborruso/599153968878f452bd3c68f3de0f29c4/raw/1156d224a4290393409ceef285c238c09b6bd08e/input.html"
df = pd.read_html(url)[0]
df = pd.read_html(url, converters={i:str for i in range(len(df.columns))})[0]
```